# retrieving from dictionary into list python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Right now i have a huge list with multiple dictionaries within that list. which structure looks something like this [{ u' type, u' number ....

what i'm trying to do is retrieve all dictionaries in the list by  type and add each of those into a separate list. so lets say in my list of dictionaries there are 50 entries all with a u' type. i want my new list to grab and display [type(from dict 1), type(from dict 2) and so on. I'm experiencing some errors in my code so far.

```
for bottle in houses:
  mylist = []
  mylist.append(bottle['type'])
```

Printing these results arn't giving me the expected results.

Comment: where is the colon and where is the indentation? Yoy may do like this `[bottle['type'] for bottle in houses]`

Comment: or `[bottle.get('type', None) for bottle in houses]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are redefining `mylist` as an empty list on every iteration of the loop. You need to create `mylist` before you enter the `for` loop, and then append to it inside of the loop, like so:

```
mylist = []
for bottle in houses:
    mylist.append(bottle['type'])
```

One great thing about python is something called a list comprehension, which allows you to do this in one line:

```
mylist = [bottle['type'] for bottle in houses]
```